# Shell Script to lookup a value from one column of a file to another column of another file and compare the value of 2nd column

Tags: bash, shell

I have two files - Dir.txt (gets generated everyday with top 5 directories and the bytes used)
Config.txt (user defined. it contains the directory name and the ideal size for that directory)

Dir.txt

```
|DirName|Size|
 -------|----
|/home/tmp/a_side/|85452|
|/home/tmp/b_side/|65745|
|/home/tmp_3/test/|45877|
|/home/asad/api/|2145|
|/home/zxcv/data/|125896|
```

Config.txt

```
|DirName|Ideal_Size|
 -------|----
|/home/tmp_3/test/|30000|
|/home/zxcv/data/|50000|
```

I need to write a shell script that -

1. looks up for the DirName from Dir.txt in the column DirName of Config.txt.
2. If it finds an entry the script needs to check if the Size value in Dir.txt is greater than the Ideal_Size in Config.txt for that directory.
3. if the value is greater then compress the files in the directory.

Example:
Directory /home/tmp_3/test/ has size 45877 in Dir.txt. this Directory is present in Config.txt as well and the size is greater than the Ideal_size (45877 > 30000). In this case the script should zip the files present in /home/tmp_3/test/.

Comment: First create an associative array from `Config.txt`. Then loop through `Dir.txt`, looking up the `DirName` in the array, and comparing the Size with the array value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, here is an idea:

```
#! /bin/bash
sed -n '1,2 d ; s/\(|\)\(.*\)\(|\)/\2/w config.sorted' config.txt
sed -n '1,2 d ; s/\(|\)\(.*\)\(|\)/\2/w dir.sorted' dir.txt
join --nocheck-order -t '|' dir.sorted config.sorted > joined.txt
dir_size=($(cat joined.txt | cut -d '|' -f2))
allowed_size=($(cat joined.txt | cut -d '|' -f3))
folder=($(cat joined.txt | cut -d '|' -f1))
for i in $(seq 0 $((${#folder[@]}-1)))
do
    if [ ${dir_size[$i]} -ge ${allowed_size[$i]} ]
    then
        gzip -r ${folder[$i]}
    fi
done    

rm ./dir.sorted ./config.sorted ./joined.txt
```

Lets break it down:

```
sed -n '1,2 d ; s/\(|\)\(.*\)\(|\)/\2/w config.sorted' config.txt
sed -n '1,2 d ; s/\(|\)\(.*\)\(|\)/\2/w dir.sorted' dir.txt
```

**`sed`**
stream editor, a very useful tool for editing text.
The `-n` flag makes the command not print out any output to the terminal.
`'1,2 d'` erases the first 2 rows which contain no useful data.
`'s/expression1/expression2/w dir.sorted'` will *substitute* expression1 with expression 2.
in this case expression1 is divided into 3 segments:

1. '|' at the start
2. any combination of characters
3. '|' at the end

So, in our case expression1 is any expression with a '|' character at its start and end.
Expression2 is simply whatever is in the second set of parentheses.
The 'w' at the end means write out to the specified file.

```
'join --nocheck-order -t '|' dir.sorted config.sorted > joined.txt'
```

Next the **`join`** command which joins 2 files together based on given settings.
In our case:
`--nocheck-order` will tell it to not check if the files are sorted as it doesn't really make a difference to us.
`-t '|'` will tell it to separate the files into segments using the given character as a seperator.
after those flags the 2 files to join are given and the output is exported to a file.

```
dir_size=($(cat joined.txt | cut -d '|' -f2))
allowed_size=($(cat joined.txt | cut -d '|' -f3))
folder=($(cat joined.txt | cut -d '|' -f1))
```

So now we simply define 3 arrays using the manipulated text files.
In short, the `cut` command cuts the given string using the '|' character as a delimiter (using the -d flag). After the string has been cut we ask `cut` to only output the wanted field by number; for instance if we are given the following string:

"/home/tmp_3/test/|45877|30000"

by using the `cut` command the string will be separated into 3 fields:

1. /home/tmp_3/test/
2. 45877
3. 30000

each of these is then injected into a corresponding array. In our case the entire file is the given string and so the entire file is cut into 3 columns and each column is injected into an array where each cell of that array is actually  a row in those columns.

In the end we have 3 arrays containing the folder sizes, the allowed sizes and the folder names.

```
for i in $(seq 0 $((${#folder[@]}-1)))
do
    if [ ${dir_size[$i]} -ge ${allowed_size[$i]} ]
    then
      gzip -r ${folder[$i]}
    fi
done
```

Next we iterate over those arrays, comparing the folder size to the allowed size and if the folder size is greater or equal to the allowed size a compression of the files inside the folder is done using gzip.

```
rm ./dir.sorted ./config.sorted ./joined.txt
```

Finally, the last line cleans up the files created by the script.

Hope this helps you!

Comment: Thanks for the script and the explanation. I tried using this script and it returns only the first match between config.txt and dir.txt. 
Another row of the config.txt (/home/tmp_3/test/) is not returned even though it is present in the dir.txt.

Comment: Also, the joined.txt contains only one row 

cat joined.txt
/home/zxcv/data/|125896|50000

Comment: I found out that the directory names with underscore in the name are getting ignored in the joined.txt. When I remove the underscore from the directory name the script works fine. is there a way to overcome this limitation?

Comment: interesting, it seems to work just fine on my end using git bash. What shell are you using?

Comment: I am using KSH shell

Comment: They shouldn't be ignored unless they do not match to what is in the dir.txt file. I would start by examining the output of the sed commands and see if somehow there is an issue with the editing of the files. If you find the output to be simillar, try and pass the joim command a controlled input. Once we found whuch command is troublesome it would be easy to debug.